# ¿Cómo concatenar los valores únicos de una variable?

Tags: r

Estoy calculando promedios sobre distintos grupos de datos, lo que quiero es obtener los factores que se vieron involucrados en estos, a modo de ejemplo usare la base de datos de iris del R:

```
iris  %>%  summarise(mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length), n_distinct(Species))
```

esto me esta devolviendo el promedio de esa variable y lo mas cercano a lo que busco es usar el `n_distinct`, es decir, que 3 especies fueron promediadas,

```
mean.sepal n_distinct(Species)  
1   5.843333               3
```

pero lo que necesito obtener seria lo siguiente:

```
mean.sepal alguna funcion   
1   5.843333               setosa-versicolor-virginica
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que buscas es concatenar los nombre de las especies en una única cadena

```
library("tidyverse")
iris  %>%  
  summarise(mean.sepal = mean(Sepal.Length),
            Especies = paste(unique(Species), collapse = "-"))

  mean.sepal                    Especies
1   5.843333 setosa-versicolor-virginica
```

Con `paste(unique(Species), collapse = "-")` obtenemos los únicos nombre de especie y los pegamos separados por un `-`

Comment: creo que me entendiste mal , al utilizar el group by , me esta devolviendo esa media por especie, lo que yo busco es tener una "unica media" es decir mi salida debiese ser la media y una variable que contenga la concatenacion de las 3 especies, pero creo que me explique un poco mal.

estoy trabajando con millones de datos, y igualmente en ese proceso utilizo el group by, pero lo que necesito es basicamente es un unico promedio y la concatenacion.

Comment: @BastianAndres, si, te había entendido mal, fijate mi última edición